# Condition that a homeomorphism is an isometry

Tags: differential-geometry

The statement that every isometry is a homeomorphism is true (correct me if I am wrong). What is the condition for any homeomorphism is an isometry? In particular, is it true that any homeomorphism from a 2-sphere is an isometry?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Homeomorphisms wrk with general topological spaces, isometries require metrics. Especially, even if $f\colon (X,d)\to (Y,d')$ is an isometry, we could replace $d'$ with $\frac 12d'$ and with respect to that metric $f\colon (X,d)\to (Y,\frac12d')$ would still be a homeomorhism, but not an isometry (if $Y$ has at least two points).

The trick with simlpy changing one metric may fail if we have $X=Y$ and require the same metric to be used on both sides.
But here's a homeomorphism $S^2\to S^2$ that is not an isometry with respect to *any* metric on $S^2$ inducing the usual topology: 
$$f(x,y,z) = \frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-\frac12)^2}}\cdot(x,y,z-\frac12). $$

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant with respect to ordinary Euclidean distance.

Comment: @HaganvonEitzen: Can you explain why $f$ cannot be an isometry? Thanks.

Comment: @John because all points except the poles converge to the south pole under iteration of $f$.